# Position dynamic height footer bottom whilst staying in flow

Tags: html, css, css-float, css-tables

In [this](http://jsfiddle.net/7yaw4/) example I have a two column content. The left column is fixed width and the right one is dynamic width, depending on the parent. `min-height` is 300px and I want both columns align at the bottom, when one has higher content. This I did with tables.

The problem is I can not position the elements `.dw-bottom-fixed` to the bottom whilst letting them stay in flow (so [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068997/position-text-at-bottom-but-letting-it-stay-in-document-flow/#answer-13070015) wont work), so that higher content pushes the content down and if the content is too short it should stay at the bottom. And that on both sides.

Footer content is also of dynamic height so I cant do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268410/footer-not-flowing-to-bottom-of-page/#answer-2268499) either.

And I **DONT** want to do this via javascript.

Have any guesses?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really would have want a solution where I could pull down an element with a css class but my solution was to put the elements to be at the bottom in another `display: table-row`.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NH57X/).